# Paypal mass pay soap php integration

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I want to implement Mass Pay feature and looking over source code for php
https://www.x.com/paypal-apis-masspay-php-5.3/soap

There is a snippet of a code that goes like this

```
for($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
    $receiverData = array(  'receiverEmail' => "user$i@paypal.com",
                            'amount' => "example_amount",
                            'uniqueID' => "example_unique_id",
                            'note' => "example_note");
    $receiversArray[$i] = $receiverData;
}
```

What exactly is uniqueID and how does that get generated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UniqueID would be your own internal ID you may have to identify the payment.  You could generate it however you want.

In most cases it would be your customer ID or an order ID of some sort.  Or just a payment record ID from your own system so you can easily cross-reference with PayPal.

Answer (score 0):

As I see in that page, PayPal doesn't force you to create uniqID with a specific method. So you have many options at this point.

Pseudos;

```
uniqid('', true);
sha1(uniqid(mt_rand(), true) . microtime());
hash('ripemd128', uniqid(mt_rand(), true) . microtime());
base64_encode(pack("H*", sha1(microtime())));

// should be more secure
bin2hex(mcrypt_create_iv(64, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM));

sprintf('%04X%04X-%04X-%04X-%04X-%04X%04X%04X', 
    mt_rand(0, 65535), mt_rand(0, 65535), mt_rand(0, 65535), 
    mt_rand(16384, 20479), mt_rand(32768, 49151), mt_rand(0, 65535), 
    mt_rand(0, 65535), mt_rand(0, 65535));

$len = 128;
$str = '';
while ($len--) {
    $str .= chr(rand(33,126));
}

$str = '';
$chars = str_shuffle('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ');
for ($i = 0; $i < 62; $i++) {
    $str .= $chars[$i];
}
```